# Is there a way to embed a compile-time dynamic timestamp in a Flash AS3 movie?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compile-time-constant

Background: I manually update a version timestamp in my Flash document, which is displayed on the log-in screen of the application at run time.  This helps me verify that I have the latest version loaded in the browser, rather than some cached version.

The declaration for the variable is:

```
public static var version:String = "v 2012.11.14.1854"; //yyyy.mm.dd.hhmm
```

Is there a way to have this value automatically updated to the current system time when the document is compiled in the flash IDE?  Perhaps with some kind of "compile time variable".

Comment: I've seen solutions that read the bytes of the SWF and extract the compile time, but that involves reading from a SWF_SERIALNUMBER structure that's present only in Flex-compiled SWFs from what I've read.  I'm never used the JSFL API, but I know it can open and read/write project files, so perhaps I could have it re-write the timestamp in my main file, although I'd rather have a solution that doesn't require saving such a precise modification to an actual class file in my project.  As I mentioned, some kind of "compile time variable" would be perfect.

Comment: Another thing I saw was FlashDevelop automatically defines a CONFIG::timeStamp compiler-constant set to the current date, but it doesn't include the time and you can't configure it to include the time, so it's useless.

Comment: you want this to be changed in the class? I think the JSFL could be good option as it can do some work before publishing then publish your file e.g. open file (your class), search for version, replace with new values gathered from Date object, save file, open fla then publish it.

Comment: Unless you find an already defined compile time constant (like the timeStamp but with actual time info) I don't think you'll be able to do this.  We were doing something similar using maven for compilation since there's a version plugin written that made it easy to get the timestamp and build user and have them written into an XML file that was then read by the service code for a "getVersion" call to verify everything deployed correctly.  You can probably do the same here if you've got maven involved in your build process already, if not its probably a bit much to take on for just this issue.

Comment: I would prefer to leave the class file alone with something like "public static var version:String = CONFIG::timeStamp", where CONFIG::timeStamp is set by the compiler with the format "v yyyy.mm.dd.hhmm", rather than the useless one that FlashDevelop includes "yyyy/mm/dd".  I'm really just trying to save myself the trouble of remembering to set it manually each time I compile.  I'd rather compile, deploy to server, test, and see that it was just compiled, instead of seeing that I forgot to update the timestamp, lol and have to compile, deploy, test again.

Comment: You're supposed to compile code in Flash.  It is made for it.  A lot of the code is classes linked to library symbols, so it only makes sense to compile them in Flash.  The alternative would be to link in a separate SWC file, but then changes to the code would require compiling twice (the SWC and then the Flash document with the library symbols).  You also can't link library symbols directly to classes in an externally compiled SWC.

Direct modification of the SWF, and runtime parsing of it would be a last resort.  It's too low-level and would have to be maintained for newer SWF versions.

Answer (score 0):

a) You can create ANT task to build, and there you can set variables, but its a rather complicated solution if you're developing alone and not using SVN or Perforce.

b) I'm not sure if it'll work, but use additional compiler arguments (project properties > Actionscript Compiler)

```
-date text
```

this sets metadata in the resulting SWF file. I'm not sure, how you can access it, I haven't tested it.